# Is it possible to use taxonomy term's field as exposed filter in Services Views?

Tags: 7, views, services

I would like create a REST endpoint which would allow a user to pass a query parameter that is incidentally a field of a taxonomy term. I am trying to achieve this by using Services Views in Drupal 7.

To simplify the problem, let's say I have a list of players and each player has a name and a skill level. For example, the unfiltered JSON output of my API would be

```
   [{"name": "John98","level": "Beginner"}, ...
    {"name": "PetePete", "level": "Advanced"}]
```

But the level is actually a taxonomy term, that also has a "min_points" integer field, for example 0 for "beginner" and 50 for "advanced" and 1000 for "expert".

In my API would like to do smth like 
http://example.com/api/players?points>45 and get all the players with levels that correspond to more than 45 points.

Is this possible to achieve? Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: It is possible with the `Views datasource`'s sub module called `Views JSON`. Essentially you just build the View as you normally would, add the exposed filter, then append that filter to the URL when making the call for the JSON data: `api/players?points=45`

Comment: Would it also be possible to do points>45?

Comment: I have also seen that this module is not covered by the security policy, so I am not very confident about integrating it:  https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource

Comment: The `=` in the query string doesn't literally mean equality, it'll listen to whatever `op` you have selected on your exposed filter. So if your `op` is set to `less than` then the equal sign will listen to that op. As for the module not being covered by the security policy, I understand your concerns, but personally I've been using the module for about 7 years without issue in numerous production environments.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein Ok, thank you very much! Will try to solve my issue using your approach